# Como exibir objetos JS na view

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic

Já há uma pergunta do nosso amigo **Vinicius Scaramel** com esse problema, porem não há nenhuma resposta solução, então vamos lá:

Estou trazendo um objeto no formato `JSON` via `http.get` no `Ionic`, (utilizando AngularJS), porém na hora de exibi-lo na `view` com `{{}}` ele somente exibe `[object Object]`, e não exibe meu objeto em si... já estou perdendo meus cabelos tentando resolver. Vamos ao código:

Função do meu provider que da o `GET`

```
 getChamadoSelecionado(){
    return this.http.get(this.LINK + "/chamadoSelecionado");
  }
```

meu array recebendo meu objeto através do `GET`

```
ionViewDidLoad() { //funcao que é executada quando abre a view
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad ChamadoPage');
  this.ChamadosProvider.getChamadoSelecionado().subscribe(    // chamando minha funcao que da o GET na minha api, e retorna o objeto
    data => {
      const objeto_retorno = JSON.parse((data as any)._body); // inserindo na variavel os dados que preciso que estão em data._body (convertido em objeto atraves do JSON.parse)
      this.objetoChamadoSelecionado = objeto_retorno;   //atribuindo o objeto ao meu array
      console.log(this.objetoChamadoSelecionado);    
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
```

até aqui esta tudo correndo muito bem, dando um `console.log` na minha variável que recebeu o retorno do `JSON` esta lindo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da minha `View`

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Chamado</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding >

<div ><p>{{objetoChamadoSelecionado}}</p></div>


</ion-content>
```

Aqui é onde ele deveria exibir meu objeto, porem ele exibe somente isso 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ja tentei

> objetoChamadoSelecionado.numero

por exemplo, e não consigo nada... O mais estranho de tudo é que em outra page que tenho um retorno de uma lista de objetos, utilizando um *ngFor funciona...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você mesmo respondeu a sua pergunta no final rs, basta usar o *ngFor:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of objetoChamadoSelecionado">
        <div ><p>{{ item.numero }}</p></div>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Só por dessa forma:

{{ objetoChamadoSelecionado | json }}